# continue Media Player in Fragment (playing the song) from Main Activity even when going to different Actitvity

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I have a Media Player UI in a Fragment in Main Activity which plays all songs from the emulator. Below this fragment I have List of Playlists. I can click on any of the playlists name and second activity opens with names of songs in that playlist. What I want is that after navigating to new Activity I should still be able to see the same fragment from Main Activity playing the song with Title and Artist name. Also I have to maintain the current state of player like seekbar progress irrespective doing back and forth between multiple activities. Can this be achieved without having to create a new Fragment (and thus have fragment to fragment data sharing) in second Activity and instead load the Fragment from Main Activity as it is? If new Fragment needs to be created in Second Activity how should I pass the song detail like Album art, Title, Artist etc. from first fragment to second fragment?

Comment: Have you ever tried out to minimise the fragment in the main activity?, just give it a shot!

Comment: Do what most players do, create the player in a foreground service (notification), then switching through different activities doesn't touch the service. Then you can update your UI from the service with intents.

Comment: But can the UI elements like Play, Next buttons and album art, artist name etc also be put foreground service. I have a service class to play song in background. Should I put the UI in that service class. Also I have to maintain the current state of player like seekbar progress irrespective doing back and forth between multiple activities. Can you guide me about this?

Comment: @Pierre I have not been able to see an example of media player in foreground service but connected to the app. Can you share such an example source?

Comment: @sakibshaikh Have a look at telegrams source code, maybe you can get some insight on how to proceed: MediaController [:1742]- https://github.com/DrKLO/Telegram/blob/master/TMessagesProj/src/main/java/org/telegram/messenger/MediaController.java then the AudioPlayerCell [:211] - https://github.com/DrKLO/Telegram/blob/master/TMessagesProj/src/main/java/org/telegram/ui/Cells/AudioPlayerCell.java